# InfluxDB time mismatch when connecting it through php

Tags: php, influxdb

I am using influx db php client:

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-php

I am inserting points in a measurement using php. I am using the function `strtotime($date)` to get the timestamp in seconds of `$date`. I have also set the database precision to seconds.

When I query `select * from measurementname` I can see the timestamp in secods.

For `precision rfc3339` I get `2016-08-08T18:30:00Z`.

For `precision s` I get`1470681000`.

now if i do `date('Y-m-d H:s:i',1470681000)` in php, the ouptout is `2016-08-09 00:00:00`.

I don't undertand why there is a difference in time: `2016-08-08T18:30:00Z` and `2016-08-09 00:00:00`.

P.S. My timezone is `Asia/Kolkata`

Comment: I am getting json 404 error in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the php time zone that is being used i.e. `Asia/Kolkata`,since influxDB stores time in `UTC`.Changing it to timezone `UTC` in php script solved the problem.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC')
```

Above command can be used to change the timezone to `UTC`.